# R script error with ggplot2 package in Power Bi - could not find function "after_stat"

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

I have written a R script to create a histogram with cumulative counts on it. It works well in R studio and it works in PowerBI desktop during development, but when I publish in Power BI service, the visual created from this script shows **Script Runtime Error**:

```
Error in after_stat(count/sum(count)) :   could not find function "after_stat"
```

In the script, I loaded ggplot2.

I raised a ticket with Microsoft team and they have been working on this last few days, but so far no solutions. I am wondering, if I can get a solution here, or after_stat function can be replaced with an equivalent?

Comment: Instead of `after_stat()` you could try with `..count../sum(..count..)`.

Comment: Yes great, I have just tried that and published again. I think it will work. While preparing this code with the help of this sites experts, I read somewhere that after_stat have some alternate to be used sometimes. Will revert result soon.

Comment: It works fine. You can please mark the question as answered. Thanks again.